# How to describe a category with only two objects by string diagram?

Tags: category-theory

I'm learning string diagram (self-study).

In wikipedia, it says that

> an object is represented by a portion of plane
>
> a 1-cell $f : A → B$ is represented by a vertical segment—called a string—separating the plane in two (the right part corresponding to $A$ and the left one to $B$)

But what if a category $C$ has only two objects $A$ and $B$ and there is no morphism between them?

How to describe this category by string diagram?

Does this means that object A and B will share (overlap) the same portion in string diagram (because there is no string separate them)?

Thanks.

Comment: String diagrams aren't for representing categories, they're for representing computations in categories.

Comment: @jgon What do you mean by "representing computations" ? Can I understand string diagram as another form of standard commutative diagram? That means in a standard commutative diagram, it is impossible to have two objects with no morphism between them. I am right?

Comment: Well they're more useful for representing computations in categories with extra structure, like 2-categories. For example, [the triangle identities](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/triangle+identities#AsStringDiagrams) are identities in a 2-category, which can be represented via string diagrams.

Comment: @jgon I understand. Very thanks.